# self.view.frame.width returns 0 in Custom Keyboard View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to get the frame width with the following code, it simply returns 0:

```
var deviceWidth = self.view.frame.width
```

I am assuming that this has something to do with the restrictions of the UIInputViewController class, which is the superclass of all custom keyboards

Comment: Have you tried self.view.size.width?

Comment: One side-note that I wished I new about before... There are convenience methods for getting frame information that are pretty handy, like CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame);, or if you want to get the bottom y position of an image: CGRectGetMaxY(image.frame); Just a heads up in case you weren't aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that you can use the following code instead:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
```

Or simply:

```
view.bounds.width
```

Comment: for xcode 7.3 swift 2 ios 9.x only the former seems to work

Answer (score 1):

this is right solution

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
   CGRect keyboardRect = self.inputView.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it returns 0 until u set any view as subview. So I solwed this problem in such way: in `viewDidLoad` method I'm innitialazing all neccessary thing i need for drawing and one extra view:

```
//initialize all you need for drawing
var extraView = UIView()
self.view.addSubview(extraView)
//now you can get real size
```

Now you can start drawing in `viewDidAppear`method, where you can get real size now. This is my solution of this problem.